# Рекурсия, указатели ( с++ )

Tags: c++, указатели, рекурсия, ссылки, вывод

помогите понять как правильно понимать указатели, ссылки в с++. Я дошел до рекурсий, пытаюсь выполнить задачу на вывод чисел от 1 до 10 рекурсией, но не понимание указателей, и ссылкой не дает мне это сделать.. Посоветуйте материал, или объясните, пожалуйста, как разобраться, и понимать эту тему, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: все же стоит сначала разобраться в базисе языка, прежде чем двигаться к более сложным вещам. Вообщем указатель - это переменная, которая указывает на другую переменную или не указывает никуда (`nullptr`). Ссылка тот же указатель, но она всегда должна указывать на какую либо переменную (на самом деле нет, но можно считать что да). Ну и они различаются по доступу к переменной: чтобы достучаться до переменной по указателю нужно его разыменовать (`*`) или или использовать `->`, для ссылки этого не нужно. Это все очень упрощенно, но для базы такого понимания достаточно

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо за ответ, вроде более менее яснее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатели и ссылки не мешают Вам. Посмотрите, как можно рекурсией решить Вашу задачу без указателей и ссылок

```
#include <iostream>

void show(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    show(n-1);
    std::cout << n << " ";
}

int main() {
    show(10);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ